# Same function, variable parameters and types with lambda

Tags: c#, multithreading, wpf

In my current project, I find myself using `Dispatcher.Invoke` a lot. Before each call I test if the current dispatcher is the right one. I want to write a wrapper class like so:

```
class SafeRunner
{
    //From the thread we always need to run on
    public static System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher disp;

    public static void Run<T>(Action<T> f, T arg)
    {
        if (disp != System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher)
        {
            disp.Invoke(f, arg);
        }
        else
        {
            f(arg);
        }
    }
    public static void Run<T1, T2>(Action<T1,T2> f, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
    {
        if (disp != System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher)
        {
            disp.Invoke(f, arg1, arg2);
        }
        else
        {
            f(arg1, arg2);
        }
    }
    public static void Run<T1, T2, T3>(Action<T1,T2,T3> f, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
        {...}
    public static void Run<T1, T2, T3, T4>(Action<T1,T2,T3,T4> f, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4)
        {...}
}
```

And I can use it like this:

```
SafeRunner.Run<string,string>((a,b) => {
    doSomething(a,b);
    doSomethingElse(a);
    // Maybe a few more lines here
}, "Hello", "World");
```

This works, but doesn't *feel* right. Is there a better way?

Comment: Your invocation may be able to be written as `SafeRunner.Run(doSomething, "Hello", "World")`. The methodgroup/delegate should match the parameters already, after all. That makes it closer to the dispatcher's syntax too, which is probably a good thing.

Comment: @Magus Thanks. I was not clear in that there may be multiple lines of code. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things I notice, and they are both around the if statements

I would flip the if statements around so that they are checking the positive test.  I would also put the `disp` on the right side of the `==`.  You can eliminate the else statement, all it really does is clutters up the code.

```
if (System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher == disp)
{
    f(arg);
    return;   
}

disp.Invoke(f, arg);
```

Comment: Without the else, when `CurrentDispatcher == disp` the function will get run 2x. I only want it to run once.

Comment: Good point, for some reason I had it my head it was returning :)  You can just add a return into the if...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you call your class `SafeDispatcher`, and your methods `Invoke`, since you actually wrap a `Dispatcher` (not `Runner`), and `Invoke` (not [`Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.run) which does something completely different in `Dispatcher`).

Also, if performance is not an issue, you can use `DynamicInvoke`, and implement the whole thing in a single method:

```
class SafeDispatcher
{
    public static System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher disp;

    public static void Dispatch(Delegate f, params Object[] args)
    { 
        if (System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher == disp)
        {
            f.DynamicInvoke(args);
        }
        else
        {
            disp.Invoke(f, args);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, to call: `SafeDispatcher.Dispatch(new Action<string>((s)=>{...}), "hello");`, correct?

Comment: I believe that `SafeDispatcher.Dispatch((s)=>{...}, "hello");` should also work